# PrintWriter in a Listener crashes application

Tags: android, tcp, arduino, crash, printwriter

I want to create a very simple TCP/IP Client-Server with an Android device being the Client and an Arduino being the Server.

So this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 80;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.141";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        try {
            TextInputLayout input1 = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input1);
            String str = input1.getEditText().getText().toString();

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println(this.socket.getInetAddress().toString());
            out.flush();

        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            }
            catch(UnknownHostException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException e2){
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The phone manages to connect to the server when I boot up the application (I can see it from the Arduino's serial monitor), but when I click on the button, it crashes because of the PrintWriter class presumably.

Strange thing is, if I print a message from the run() method in the ClientThread class, then the message is sent all right.

Stranger thing is that the application does not crash when I run it through the Android Studio emulator but it does on a real device.

The problem stems from a combination of the onClick listener and PrintWriter, but I just don't get why exactly.

Comment: Application is crashing, post logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the crash likely originates from the fact that you're trying to access the `socket` variable when it is null in the case the connection to your server could not be established. The exact reason why this is the case can be found in the logs (network issue, security issue, etc. all possible).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I needed to print to the socket from another Thread as well.